# Render html from JSON file using Node.js and express-handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, handlebars.js

I have JSON files that contains some raw html (with tags) that I need to render onto a page. I read the file I need in Node then pass it to the handlebars template. However when I display the raw html using `{{this.raw_html}}`, I see actual tags (`<p></p>`) on the page.

How can I render this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To render raw HTML in Handlebars, use triple brackets, ie:

```
{{{variable}}}
```